# Extract substring between two tokens. Second token could be missing

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day,

I need to extract portion of string which can looks like this:

```
"some_text MarkerA some_text_to_extract MarkerB some_text"
"some_text MarkerA some_text_to_extract"
```

I need to extract `some_text_to_extract` in both cases. 
`MarkerA`, `MarkerB` - predefined text strings.

I tried this regexps, but with no luck:

```
".*\sMarkerA(.*)MarkerB.*" - does not work in case 2
".*\sMarkerA(.*)(?=MarkerB)?.*" - wrong result "some_text_to_extract MarkerB some_text" 
".*\sMarkerA(.*)(?:MarkerB)?.*" - does not work at all
```

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
".*\sMarkerA(.*?)(?=$|MarkerB)"
```

Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

tests = [
        ("some_text MarkerA some_text_to_extract MarkerB some_text"," some_text_to_extract "),
        ("some_text MarkerA some_text_to_extract"," some_text_to_extract")
        ]

import re
reg = re.compile(r".*\sMarkerA(.*?)(?=$|MarkerB)")

for (input,expected) in tests:
    mo = reg.match(input)
    assert mo is not None
    print mo.group(1),expected
    assert mo.group(1) == expected
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get rid of the `.*` at the beginning and the end; you don't need to match the whole string.  Then use alternation to match either the ending delimiter or the end of the string.

```
"MarkerA(.*?)(?:MarkerB|$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
".*\sMarkerA(.*)"
```

Part of the regex will match everything after MarkerA not giving a change for MarkerB or anything else to match to match. The .* is being greedy, you can use the non greedy form of * , *? to give:

```
".*\sMarkerA(.*)(?=MarkerB)?.*"
```

You probably want not to capture the space before MarkerB so in that case use:

```
".*\sMarkerA(.*)(?=\sMarkerB)?.*"
```